# Options for online setting for PHP/MySQL servers without installation on local servers?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, web-services, apache

I am trying to research this following question:

**"What are the options for online setting for PHP/MySQL servers which one can run without relying to install these services on their local servers within organisations?"**

So far I have done a bit of research of my own and found:

http://www.wampserver.com/en/ - WAMPServer
http://www.webassist.com/community/tutorials/view_tutorial.php?tid=89

Unfortunately I cannot add anymore than 2 links due to my short profile reputation.

These are useful links but the issue is that they would have to be installed on local servers and what I am looking for is quite the opposite. I'm sure that by improving my research skills I should be able to find one if I am pointed to the right direction.

Thanks for reading this message and any useful feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: pay a host to do it for you... ?

Comment: Please just pay for hosting you will get everything ready made.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have that option open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where should they install it then?

You have a Server, where PHP/MySQL is installed - or not!

You can look at virtual Linux Server, but I don't think, it's what you meant.

Or did I get the question wrong?

Comment: Thank you. Your answer points me to the right direction. After re-reading my question properly and further researching I came across cloud hosting, it doesn't appear to be free and I am new to it so I am going to do some more digging around on how to use it.

Comment: Wait, if cloud hosting is the "right direction", why isn't my answer the "ticked one"?

Answer (score 0):

For PHP you can run your script on online by using http://www.compileonline.com/execute_php_online.php

Comment: Thank you. Your answer points me to the right direction. I will use that website as reference and testing. Alternatively I have found cloud hosting and I am new at it so I will learn how to use it.

Comment: If my answer is useful to you, please up vote and tick the answer